# Fuchsia OS fx mkzedboot not working correctly

Tags: fuchsia

I fully built fuchsia - and want to flash an usb device with it.

The correct command should be

`fx mkzedboot /dev/sdb`

```
fx mkzedboot /dev/sdb
/dev/sdb - DataTraveler 3.0
Changing ownership of /dev/sdb to erhard
[sudo] password for erhard: 
Opening device...
Create new GPT partition table... 
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
done
Create new partitions... 
done
Writing zedboot for EFI
43049+0 records in
43049+0 records out
22041088 bytes (22 MB, 21 MiB) copied, 2.09618 s, 10.5 MB/s
done
Closing device.
```

It seems there are only 22MB copied - is that right?
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a "live usb stick" then `fx make-fuchsia-vol` is likely what you want

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation at [Prepare a USB flash drive to be a bootable disk](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/hardware/usb_setup), `fx mkzedboot` only enables the flash drive to netboot for pave, so you must follow the instructions for pave.

I've installed Fuchsia into my USB flash drive without paving, using `fx mkinstaller`:

- First, [configure](https://fuchsia.dev/fuchsia-src/development/build/fx#configure-a-build) with everything

```
fx set workstation.x64 \
       --with //bundles:tools,//bundles:tests,//bundles:kitchen_sink \
       --ccache
```

- Then, build

```
fx build
```

- Run `fx mkinstaller /dev/<usb_drive>` in order to write the installer into an physical (or emulated) USB drive (usnig `fx mkinstaller` on a block device not connected through USB will fail)
- Copy the USB flash drive into a disk image using `dd`. This is the "installer" disk image.
- Create an image disk with the exact size of the USB drive. This is the target disk image.
- Boot the installer using qemu-kvm, with the two disks images exposed as NVME. No network is needed for this step. EFI must be available; install **ovmf** following the instructions for your distro, or download the image directly.

```
sudo /usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
     -monitor stdio \
     -vga std \
     -machine accel=kvm \
     -m 4096\
     -device nvme,drive=nvme0,serial=deadbeaf1,num_queues=8 \
     -drive file=,if=none,id=nvme0 \
     -device nvme,drive=nvme1,serial=deadbeaf1,num_queues=8 \
     -drive file=,if=none,id=nvme1 \
     -boot once=c,menu=on \
     -net nic,macaddr=00:e0:4c:c2:85:01,model=rtl8139 \
     -net user \
     -rtc base=localtime \
     -name "Fuchsia" \
     -bios /usr/share/qemu/OVMF.fd
```

- Inside the running Fuchsia, run `installer` and choose the right target device. Then, shutdown the VM. (unplug the USB flash drive if connected)
- Once installed, boot the VM again (connect the USB if you installed there), removing the installer drive from the command line, and check what happens; try with other display drivers and framebuffer resolutions; try in a real machine.

However, once installed, the following happened to me, depending the machine settings:

- On `qemu` with standard VGA display, the system boots, but the screen goes black.
- On `qemu` with other display drivers (QLX, Vmware, etc) and in a real machine (my laptop), the screen freezes on the bootloader screen, and no debug information displayed.

In both cases, I'm able to access the shell through the serial port.